# Downshifting on a manual transmission, do you you need to do it one at a time?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, shifting

An actual use case: you're coming at a red light 200m out and you're in 3rd or 4th gear, do you need to downshift all the way to 1st gear, one gear at a time, in that span of distance, or can you simply apply the brakes gradually and when you stop, downshift directly to 1st gear ? Also how does this affect the gearbox and if someone can suggest some best practices to keep in mind around changing gears ?

Comment: There are several questions about this already, for example - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27223/skipping-gears-when-downshifting?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping gears when downshifting](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27223/skipping-gears-when-downshifting)

Comment: This is on-topic to me as it's asking about how shifting can impact a transmission, however it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An automobile transmission is engineered to keep the engine rpm in the correct range for conditions at a specific time. Consider the following:
As you approach the stop, remove the pressure on the accelerator pedal. This engages engine braking at the current speed.
One can leave the vehicle in the original gear position until the vehicle slows to the point where the rpm reaches the lowest practical engine speed (not ground speed).
Engage the clutch and continue braking, shifting to first gear and gently engaging the clutch.

One can consider that the lowest practical engine speed is the idle rpm, although one can get away with a bit lower rpm without concern. The ground speed at idle rpm will also be quite slow, permitting first gear to be engaged.

I have, in the past, used the full gear range to slow the vehicle more rapidly than the above description imparts, but after seeing a bit of wisdom, cease to do so. The wisdom suggests that it is far easier to replace brake pads than it is to replace clutch linings. The above method reduces clutch wear.

Consider also that as one approaches the stop, the traffic light changes and traffic flow permits continuing at a rate which requires a gear other than the 4th or 1st gear. Simply select the appropriate gear, engage the clutch and continue to drive in what is now the optimum range for your engine.

Comment: Please don't answer driving technique questions as they are off-topic for the site.